# С какого языка начать?

Tags: любой-язык

Доброго времени суток, так как я школота и у меня каникулы, то мне захотелось занятся каким-нибудь делом, я уже давно хотел начать учить какой-нибудь язык программирования (есть знакомые, которые самостоятельно учили языки программирования дома и ко времени поступления в институт знали программу на пару курсов вперед), сначала полегче, а потом, если понравится перейти и на разные С++
Следовательно у меня есть один вопрос: с какого языка лучше всего начинать? Чтоб он не был безнадежно устаревшим и ничем не полезным, но и был не слишком сложным в освоении. Хочется услышать ваши ответы на этот вопрос, так как я надеюсь, что многие из вас знают что лучше для новичка.
Некоторые говорят про basic, другие про paskal или python. Но с чего все-таки начать? И где в интернете можно взять годные самоучители? 
Буду благодарен за полезные ответы!

Comment: Сколько людей столько и мнений на этот вопрос.  
Начните с питона. Он даст Вам все необходимое для изучения любого другого языка и плюсом к этому научит с младых ногтей оформлять код удобочитаемо.  
Из минусов: когда захотите изучить более «низкоуровневый» язык, то будете негодовать поначалу: почему все это нельзя выразить так же просто как и питоном.

Comment: Я еще слышал, что можно попробовать начинать с basic или delphi? Но питон, вам кажется, более подходящим? Завтра займусь поиском софта и уроков.

Comment: @m1_ak бэйсик и делфи вымерли. И ещё - дождитесь хотя-бы 5 ответов на вопрос. Нужно выслушивать разные мнения

Comment: @danpetruk, рано Вы хороните бэйсик. Согласно Tiobe index за июнь этого года (Visual) Basic находится на 7 месте - сразу после C# и выше Python, Perl, JavaScript и Ruby.

Comment: @Lucky: тем не менее, мне не кажется, что Basic (а) хороший язык, (б) язык с будущим.

Comment: @VladD в офисе можно по-программировать на бейсике, я думаю язык достоен для ознакомления :)

Comment: делфи тоже рано хоронить, вполне современный язык программирования, который продолжает развиваться. Линейка Delphi XE тому доказательство, в интернете на сайте работы встречаются вакансии, которые требуют от программиста знания делфи. Особенность его в том, что он заточен под БД, удобные компоненты, быстрое проектирование позволяет создать клиентское ПО для информационной системы.

Comment: Такие вакансии зачастую предполагают поддержку старого кода, написанного на Delphi (зачастую ещё на Delphi 7 или даже младше). Новые приложения на Delphi практически не пишутся, произошёл отток специалистов в сторону C#/Java.

Comment: не скажите, я был недавно на собеседовании, так меня спрашивали там знаю ли я Delphi XE в связке с Oracle. Акцент велся именно на знание современных версий данного языка программирования.

Comment: Выберите себе большую задачу и начинайте ее делать. На том языке, который больше нравится синтаксически (и в то же время не порос мхом).

Comment: Плюсую предыдущий коммент. Я бы начал с чего-нибудь строго типизированного(думаю потом на python будет легче перейти, чем с python на язык со статической типизацией). Что-нибудь типа c#/Java - тут нет проблем с указателями и выделением памяти. Хотя, можно вполне с с++/pascal начать. И хороший вариант изучать язык с какой-то конкретной задачи. Из учебников не мог зачастую понять надуманные примеры.

Comment: @IntegralAL Вероятно, Вы устраивались в фирму, которая "подсела" на delphi. (Возможно, что интервьюер -- один из тех, кто её "подсадил"). Т.е. есть куча кода на delphi, и его надо поддерживать. Вероятно можно найти места, где требуется знание foxpro for dos. (Как Вам язык?)

@Serega Isupov для начинающего язык со строгой типизацией и излишним объявлением типов вряд ли лучше языка с динамической типизацией.

@VladD Basic был специально создан для обучения программированию. Если нужен стиль полувековой давности, то он будет вполне на уровне.

Comment: > Новые приложения на Delphi практически не пишутся

Вполне себе пишутся. Даже серийные продукты.

Comment: Подтверждаю. На делфи например написан скайп под винду.

Comment: Не, скайп это скучный и заюзанный пример )

Comment: > Вполне себе пишутся. Даже серийные продукты.

Назовите 5 новых (разработка которых была начата в пределах последних 5 лет) серийных продуктов, которые пишут на Delphi.

Comment: > Особенность его в том, что он заточен под БД
Там уже есть что-то типа LINQ?

> удобные компоненты
Это не фичи языка. Не знаю, как там сейчас, но VCL убога и глючна настолько, что при попытке её как-то поюзать хотелось плеваться.

> быстрое проектирование позволяет создать клиентское ПО для информационной системы за считанные дни. 
Это тоже не фичи языка; кроме того, они не уникальны.

Comment: > Назовите 5 новых (разработка которых была начата в пределах последних 5 лет) серийных продуктов, которые пишут на Delphi.

@Flammable, в одном нашем захолустном городе, где программистов днем с огнем не сыскать, пишется на Delphi по меньшей мере 2 серийных продукта 2мя разными конторами. Так что пяток по стране найдется ;)

Еще одной уже не пишется, так как она переформировалась и сменила профиль.

Comment: >> по меньшей мере 2 серийных продукта 2мя разными конторами

Сильно сомневаюсь, что эти продукты были начаты в пределах последних 5 лет.

Всякие qip имеют долгую историю разработки, уходящую корнями в те времена, когда не было достойных альтернатив.

Answer (score 9):

Выскажу крамольную мысль. Неважно в общем-то с какого языка начинать. Важно, что с алгоритмического (ибо есть неалгоритмические языки).

Я лично начинал с Quasic - это некая версия Basic'а для промышленных машинок.

Предвидя определенный батхерт коллег по цеху, спешу обозначить позицию: главное на начальном этапе чтобы **нравилось**, чтобы войти во вкус. Чтобы запрограммировать рученьками аналоговые часики со стрелочками смотреть на свое творение, любоваться им. Ключевое слово - любоваться. Если будете любоваться - значит "тепло" и можно дальше двигаться и освоить другой язык.

Дальше увы начинается жестокая проза - законы рынка неумолимы. Надо знать один из 3-х базовых языков на "ура": С/С++ или C# или Java. Плюсиком к этому надо подтянуть нечто скриптирующее: *a la* Python, JavaScript, Perl.

Дальше больше: чтобы стать т.н. fullstack девелопером - надо будет знать SQL, проектирование БД, неплохо бы добавить ассемблер, совершенно must have XML/XSLT/HTML, понимать устройство серверных, кластерных технологий. Куда уж без blueprints. Ну и железки тоже надо бы знать.

На все про все нужно лет 6-7 реальной пахоты. И тогда можно претендовать на $10к.

Comment: 10К баксов в месяц? Это 120К в год? Ого! Возьмёте меня к себе?

Comment: и меня ) соглашусь и на $5к

Comment: @Barmaley, и много у Вас вакансий? У меня требования ниже, чем у вышенаписавших...

Comment: @VladD, @IVsevolod, @alexlz [угощайтесь](http://www.seek.com.au/jobs/in-australia/#dateRange=31&workType=0&industry=&occupation=&graduateSearch=false&salaryFrom=120000&salaryTo=999999&salaryType=annual&advertiserID=&advertiserGroup=&keywords=java&page=1&isAreaUnspecified=false&location=3000&area=&nation=&sortMode=KeywordRelevance&searchFrom=quickupper&searchType=)

Comment: @Nofate увы, для этого списка я старый и тупой.

Comment: > и меня ) соглашусь и на $5к

@IVsevolod, отечественный игродел Nival уже полгода ищет крутого С++ программиста в дефолт-сити за $5000, да что-то никак не найдет.

Comment: @alexlz, а я молодой и тупой, где же золотая середина? ))

Comment: @Nofate ну если так, то надо сложить наши возрасты и поделить пополам.

Comment: Я же написал "претендовать на $10k" - это первое, второе я не говорил, что у меня есть такие вакансии, в третьих я не говорил, что это net, естественно gross. Такие вакансии есть и вы знаете где они есть. Hint: в Московском эквиваленте это что-то в районе $5-6k...

Comment: @Nofate увы, на С++ у меня опыт меньше 3 лет

Answer (score 7):

1. `Pascal`. И не фыркайте, что устаревший, недельку потратить можно, т.к. некоторые вещи в нем понимать проще. В том же Си синтаксис циклов и некоторых других элементов подрезан, те же скобки вместо `begin` и `end` и т.д. (это упрощает работу программисту, но может усложнить понимание принципов для того, кто только начал).
2. `Delphi (Object Pascal)` - практически тот же паскаль, только здесь уже будет чем удивить своих недалеких одноклассников, сможете писать мелкие программки для собственного применение, простенькие боты и остальные мелочи. =) Если не вдаваться в подробности, то отличается он тем, что `Pascal` - для консольных приложений, а в `Object Pascal` можно работать с окнами.
3. Ну а дальше уже пора взрослеть и переходить на `C++`. 
   Параллельно изучайте структуру компьютера, архитектуру процессоров, микроконтроллеров, структуру сетей.
4. тогда сможете перейти на `Assembler` (но в принципе, он больше для технарей, работающих с железом, чем для рядовых программистов). 
   А так... Смотрите сами, литературы по многим языкам предостаточно, по этому, любой сможете освоить.

Comment: > В том же Си синтаксис циклов и некоторых других элементов подрезан, те же скобки вместо begin и end и т.д.

Необходимо 5 секунд, чтобы освоить, что { - начало, а } - конец

Comment: Если бы мог, я бы поставил по минусу за каждый из 4 пунктов.

1) Начинать с паскаля в 2013 году - это феерия.

2) Delphi - это тоже феерия. Язык сам по себе устарел, вменяемые IDE отсутствуют.

3) Переходить с Delphi на C++ - это круто, если поставлена цель потратить как можно больше времени впустую. Сначала вы обмажетесь Delphi, а потом будете страдать, пытаясь заместить старые концепции новыми (из C++).

4) Переходить на ассемблер с C++ - это как переходить с мерседеса на запорожец. На ассемблер не нужно переходить. Когда потребуется (если вообще потребуется) - тогда вникнете, это не долго.

Comment: Вот он холивар, бесмысленный и беспощадный. Пойду еще парочку тем создам с подобными названиями :D

Comment: Flammable, с какого языка тогда посоветуете начать?  
Почему не delphi xe4? Какой тогда? Ява?

Comment: @m1_ak давайте так - что вам больше по душе - делать сайты, приложения для компа или телефона?

Comment: > вменяемые IDE отсутствуют.

Не то чтобы для подлития масла в огонь, но @Flammable, чем вам линейка XE невменяема? )

Comment: @danpetruk повторяю, что в данный момент мне хотелось бы делать что-нибудь легкое, но что может доставить удовольствия "а-ля сделал сам", пока все только для собственного удовольствия, может есть 1-2 цели,которые хочется достигнуть,  но о заработке не может быть и речи. 
Думаю, что больше меня тянет к приложением для компьютера, и сейчас у меня, по вашим рекомендцаиям, есть пара языков на примете: delphi XE4 (но на него нет уроков на русском языке), паскаль (но он устарел) или сразу переходить на что-нибудь посложнее, например язык C
(Еще плохо разобрался с системой комментариев этого сайта)

Comment: Точно по такому же пути шёл. Сейчас вот тоже на 3 пункте сижу) Тоже школоло)

Comment: @danpetruk,  
>  Необходимо 5 секунд, чтобы освоить, что { - начало, а } - конец
Не скажите, выглядит просто, но интуитивно доходит не с первого раза. Хотя быстро привыкаешь

Answer (score 7):

Сколько людей - столько мнений. С чего начать? К чему душа лежит. Мобильное, веб, системное, прикладное программирование? Определитесь с тем, что вам интересно. Я начинал с СИ, оно мне дало некую базу, фундамент в понимании программирования, а потом я для себя решил, что хочу заниматься прикладным программированием, пить кофе, сидя в офисе, и материть заказчика за кривое ТЗ. Если не будет искры на раннем этапе, не будет желания покодить для себя, а не ради "буду программистом - буду много зарабатывать", то, возможно, что программирование не для Вас. Удачи.

Answer (score 6):

Я бы посоветовал бы Вам изучить С, потом ООП - C++. Это класические языки. Когда вы уже будете ориентироваться в программировании, тогда возмитесь за изучение архитектуры компьютера, операционных систем и компьютерных сетей.

Comment: про "скучно" - это исключительно ваше предвзятое мнение. А что касается "в моде/не в моде" - это вообще чепуха. Уж что-что, а плюсам пока что никакие моды не страшны.

Comment: Я считаю, что знаний с компьютерных наук должны формироваться с самого низкого уровня иерархии. Если сразу начинать изучений компьютерных наук с JavaScript, то у вас будут отсуствовать знания низов

Comment: люто плюсую. В противном случае можно видеть толпы слабоумных малолеток, едва знающих php и мнящих из-за этого себя гуру всея компьютерных наук

Comment: > Я считаю, что знаний с компьютерных наук должны формироваться с самого низкого уровня иерархии. 

дык зачем они нужны? Да, отличать компиляцию и интерпретацию надо, что такое ассемблер - тоже надо знать. Но ради этого изучать C...

Лично я как рассуждаю -  нужно знать всё, что относится к языку. Ну там понимать как он исполняется и т.д. и т.п. Но зачем знания низов например js developer -ам? Я не могу это понять

Comment: >Но зачем знания низов например js developer -ам?

потому что иначе из него получится ремесленник, мнящий себя мастером

Comment: > затем что иначе из него получится ремесленник, мнящий себя мастером

Вы считаете личным оскорблением то, что кто-то может быть специалистом в какой-то конкретной области, не зная низкого уровня?

Comment: @Flammable, ключевой вопрос был "может ли?". Без знаний низкого уровня и сетей, для веб-разработки (*да, я постоянно говорю про сети*), человек сам себе ставит потолок.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, можно взять любую область IT и сказать, что не изучая ее, каждый конкретный человек ставит себе потолок. Вы считаете, что низкоуровневое программирование имеет какой-то приоритет перед всеми остальными областями?

Comment: @Flammable, я считаю, что незнание ограничивает. А вы придумываете слишком много:

> Вы считаете личным оскорблением то..

> Вы считаете, что низкоуровневое программирование имеет какой-то приоритет..

Comment: >Вы считаете личным оскорблением


@Flammable вместо ответа процитирую сказанное выше: 

>А вы придумываете слишком много того, о чём не говорилось

Comment: @xEdelweiss, незнание, безусловно, ограничивает. Но оно присуще всем без исключения. Так почему незнающими выставляются те самые js-девелоперы? Эта нездоровая традиция не несет внутри себя ничего, кроме поглаживания собственного ЧСВ "я знаю ассемблер, а веб-программисты нет".

Comment: @danpetruk мне кажется вы не понимаете что такое компиляция…

Comment: @danpetruk  основано на вашей предудущей теме

Comment: @danpetruk, имхо, добавлю, что низшим называют абсолютным кодом.

Comment: @alexlz, речь об компиляторах, а не об интерпретаторах

Comment: @danpetruk Вы это не написали, вы это скопипастили из вики. Это две разные вещи. Да и я делаю выводы по тому, что вы тут пишите… я бы вам посоветал взять K&R блокнот и gcc с терминалом и сидеть вникать.

Comment: @Jetu я это написал по памяти, мало того, я ещё и не согласен с вики. Я пишу "в более низший", а вики пишет "в язык низкого уровня". То есть по мнению вики из dart в js - не компиляция, но это не так

Comment: @danpetruk, вики права. Это не компиляция. Даже то что называют компиляцией Java в байт-код не является компиляцией. Это преобразование. Компиляцией в случае Java будет JIT. Ну а преобразование в язык высокого уровня из синтаксического сахара совсем никак не может быть компилированием.

Comment: @ReinRaus вики про typescript:

> TypeScript является обратно совместимым с JavaScript и **компилируется** в последний

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript

Или более официально:

> 
Dart code can be executed in two different ways: either on a native virtual machine or on top of a JavaScript engine by using a **compiler** that translates Dart code to JavaScript.

http://googlecode.blogspot.ru/2011/10/dart-language-for-structured-web.html

Comment: @danpetruk, Вы придираетесь к словам, но не видите сути.

>Компиляция — трансляция программы, составленной на исходном языке высокого уровня, в эквивалентную программу на низкоуровневом языке, близком машинному коду (абсолютный код, объектный модуль, иногда на язык ассемблера)

Суть компилятора в трансляции языка высокого уровня в машинный код (или близкий к нему). Dart же транслирует код на языке высокого уровня в код на другом языке высокого уровня.

Comment: @forilton откуда дровишки (тоесть определение)? И является ли оно узаконено каким-то стандартом, пусть и не шибко официальным?

Comment: @alexz, дровишки из вики: [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)][1]. Обратите внимание, там внизу ссылки на толковые словари. Насчёт стандартов не знаю, вряд ли кто-то пытался это стандартизировать.

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @fori1ton сейчас вспомним, что backend'ом для языков высокого уровня бывает Си "и опять пойдёт морока про коварный зарубеж"... Похоже просто уже разговор ни о чём.

Comment: @danpetruk честно, нечете чушь какую то… идите пишите сайтики за 5 дней на джумле, это ваш уровень…

Comment: @Jetu даа, так меня ещё никто не оценивал. Надо будет в следующий раз притворяться, что не знаю js - плохо он на репутацию влияет :)

Comment: @alexlz, если подняться до такого уровня абстракции- у меня есть рабочий код:  

    Надо, чтобы на экране была кнопка при нажатии на которую вылетает ядро из пушки, которая нарисована над кнопкой, и при этом играет забавный какой-нибудь звук.
Данный код компилируется в код для PVM (Python Virtual Machine) ну то бишь получаем обычный код питона, но так как мы уже привыкли писать программы на чистом русском языке, то питон мы считаем низкоуровневым.  
Сравнение возможно не совсем корректно, но как можно считать результатом компиляции то, что может быть скомпилировано к еще более низкому уровню

Comment: @ReinRaus слишком глубокая для меня философия. Если так, то конечный результат -- потоки электронов и фотонов. Вроде так, но для работы абсолютно неприменимо. Да и вообще термин "компиляция" сложился исторически (compile -- составлять, собирать) и понять его не углубляясь в историю тяжело. Так что лучше сразу определять, о чём речь, и выражаться яснее. А то опять получится "создание сокета". В исполняемый файл -- это конечная фаза? Или надо смотреть, что будет после загрузчика?

Есть пример интересней. Транслируете и линкуете программу, а потом запускаете её под эмулятором...

Answer (score 6):

1. Изучать нужно не язык, а программирование. Алгоритмы, структуры данных и тому подобное (при этом аргумент "в Java/C#/Python/<другой язык> все нужные структуры уже реализованы" не прокатывает - знание их внутреннего устройства крайне полезно для программиста). Синтаксис языка играет тут не самую важную роль, от него требуется лишь чтобы он не был слишком сложным для начинающих программистов.
2. См п. 3.
3. А если изначально учиться под строгую, то изначально приучаешься к дисциплине и избегаешь множества досадных косяков при разработке на языках с динамической типизацией.

Answer (score 3):

Python - язык очень простой, документации и книг много, синтаксис логичный, даст представление об ООП в самой простой форме. На нем пишут все, от веб разработчиков до NASA и CCP Games. Так что берем Марка Лутца и учим.
А потом можно к C++ переходить и только после этого, на мой взгляд, можно браться за Assembler и ниже и ниже.

Comment: А ниже ассемблера -- что? Написание микропрограмм для процессоров с микропрограммным управлением? Вряд ли тут можно найти много вакансий.

Comment: Всегда есть уровень ниже, ниже ассемблера идет работа с железом, в моем понимании.

Comment: @Ukeo То, что я написал -- это уже железо. Работа с CAD'ами и паяльником -- это уже не программирование. (Работа с осциллографом вполне может входить в обязанности программиста для встраиваемого оборудования. Только тут языком может быть и Си, и что-нибудь другое)

Answer (score 2):

Начинайте с С. При чем пишите все в блокноте ручками и компилируйте в командной строке. Да, может меня сейчас заминусуют, но я убежден, что программист, должен понимать как компилируется его код, как все устроено на низком уровне. Вам потом, в будущем, будет намного легче. Докапывайтесь до всего, никогда не останавливайтесь на "а нахрена мне знать как устроен ArrayList в java, я использую и все !". Всегда пытайтесь решить задачу более лаконичным образом, чем вы написали только что, все время критикуйте свой код.

Когда будете чувствовать себя уверенно в С, да и вообще в программировании, не забываем, что язык это всего лишь инструмент, можете постепенно перебираться на какой нибудь объектно-ориентированный язык. Решите для себя чем вы хотите заняться ! Веб, мобильная разработка, детскопные приложения. После этого смотрите какой язык вам больше подходит по душе, не бойтесь эксперементировать ! Если вам интересен веб, то тут стоит выбор фронтенд разработка или бекенд. Во фронтенде все понятно HTML + CSS + JS, если бекенд, то PHP/Python/Java/ASP.NET/Ruby…

Comment: Все-таки я посоветовал бы для начала что-нибудь попроще, типа Питона, Паскаля или той же Жабы. А вот вторым-третьим языком - однозначно Си. А через нескольких месяцев - легкая экскурсия в ассемблер, чтобы знать, как все это устроено изнутри. И тогда все будет на месте.

Comment: @mikillskegg а какой конкретно ассемблер Вы бы посоветовали?

Comment: @alexlz, для общего ознакомления - без разницы.

Answer (score 1):

Чтото никто про Java не ляпнул

А еще можно было бы вспомнить про php и веб программинг

Вообще парень начинай с C# и не спрашивай лабудень

Если бы время можно было бы отмотать назад, то тогда бы я начал изучение именно с C# и не тратил бы время на Delphi

Можешь еще PHP учить тоже не плохо

Лично мое нескромное мнение что программировать нужно на удобных обьектно ориентированных языках, которые больше всего востребованы и не раздуты за счет рекламы

Конечно можно начать и с С++ но придется вникать и понимать

Delphi паскаль устарел

java корява и раздута за счет рекламы, в штатах на автобусах ее реклама  гласящая за джавой будущее

perl почти испустил дух

басик школьный сад для учителя информатики

руби - язык для извращенцев и любителей креативности, таких вот няшек в очках на носу и эйпловской продукции

питон - не для россии

Comment: > Чтото никто про Java не ляпнул

Надо признать, вы тут знатно ляпнули :)

Comment: яндекс относительно питона в недоумении. бобук вообще в шоке, наверное.

Comment: > питон - не для россии

Не поверите, на питоне и Qt пишут у нас даже в медучреждениях )

> руби - язык для извращенцев и любителей креативности, таких вот няшек в очках на носу и эйпловской продукции

хм, надо девушке мак купить все же )

Comment: 1) Чем корява java?

2) Чем не для России python?

3) Ну и что там про ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Начинай с **Delphi** или **Pascal** - т.к. синтаксис Pascal-я создавалась для обучения начинающих программистов!

Если вы хотите Web технологии, то сначало за **HTML** с каким нибудь **PHP** или тем же **Python**

Comment: @IVsevolod В плане обучения программированию, если не ошибаюсь, pascal был вторым. Первым -- basic.

Comment: @alexlz возможно :)

Comment: pascal был не первым точно я еще помню algol-60 и его версию для машины Odra-1900 бала такая польская техника а basic - а еще тогда и в помине не было. Год примерно 1989 - 1990 мой первый курс. А вообще разницы по моему нет с чего начинать. Что для вас проще с того и начинайте. А насчет basic - а в то время говорили если человек начал изучать программирование с basic-а программистом никогда не будет.

Comment: @vars62 я писал про языки для обучения программированию. А так есть пара долгожителей (постарше алгола-60) -- фортран и лисп. Правда, современные диалекты от первых сильно отличаются (не говоря уже о том, что языком для написания программ для компутеров лисп стал несколько позже)

А basic в 1989 году точно был, причём много самых разных васиков было.

Answer (score 0):

Я начинал со Small Basic, перешел на Delphi (потомок паскаля), делал игры на Lua. Это позволило мне без особых усилий разобраться в C/C++.

Попробуй начать со [Small Basic](http://smallbasic.ru)! Весьма простой язык, хорошие и простые уроки. Освоили с приятелем основы по скайпу за один вечер. На следующий день уже делал SmallPaint. :)

Answer (score 0):

Учите тот язык, который вносит больше ясности чем путаницы; на котором приятно писать и легко компилировать; для которого существуют инетгрированные средства и документация.
Не покупайте кучу литературы, благо все есть в сети. Смотрите видеоуроки в ютьюбе. Участвуйте в собеседованиях. Набирайтесь опыта.

Answer (score 0):

Не учи ЯП, учи англиский! Учи математику, структуры, алгоритмы. По дороге разберись с ООП.

для практических задач возьми C(си). Позже легко разберешься с любым ЯП.

вот например:

- http://progbook.ru/ выбирай)
- http://progbook.ru/algoritmy/1159-levitin-algoritmy-vvedenie-v-razrabotku-i-analiz.html
- http://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/cormen.pdf
- http://www.lektorium.tv/course/22823

Answer (score -3):

Если вы начнёте изучать Basic, C# и другие простые языки программирования, вы уже никогда не переучитесь на более сложный. Идеальным началом (да и не началом) являются языки ООП (Объектно-ориентированное программирование). К таким относятся: Java, C++, Python. Языки типа C++ являются **гибридными** ООП, т.е. в них недоступна большая часть ООП. Есть языки **чистого** ООП, к примеру, Java.
А напоследок скажу вам, что если вас "тянет" писать на каком-то языке, то пишите на нём. Это будет правильнее. Сейчас здесь почти каждый пытался отстоять достоинства "своего" языка и убедить вас, что другие языки плохие. Это не так. У каждого языка программирования есть своя цель. Например, С++ почти универсален, php для веб-дизайна, Prolog для изучения искусственного интеллекта.

Comment: -1. Объясню, почему.

> Если вы начнёте изучать Basic, C# и другие простые языки программирования, вы уже никогда не переучитесь на более сложный

Это кто вам такое сказал?

> Идеальным началом ... К таким относятся: Java, C++, Python.

Внезапно: C# тоже объектно-ориентированный язык. C# несколько более сложный и предоставояет больше возможностей, нежели Java.

Comment: Но при большой нагрузке программа, написанная на C#, будет занимать в разы больше оперативной памяти, чем таже самая Java.

А насчёт изучения более сложных языков, так это мой личный опыт. Сам знаю LibertyBasic, Java. Но мне с огромным трудом даётся Haskell (кстати, в чём его плюсы? стоит ли его учить дальше?)

Comment: Не верится что-то. Я учил языки в таком порядке: Basic, php, VBA, JavaScript, python, java, erlang, 1C. В соответствии с Вашей теорией я никогда не смог бы это сделать.  
Изначально надо научиться строить алгоритмы, язык не принципиален, но конечно начинать с чего то вроде erlang совсем не стоит.  

> У каждого языка программирования своя цель

У всех языков одна цель- описывать алгоритмы. Можно и на асме написать сайт, но , PHP как-то лучше для этого подходит.

Comment: >Но при большой нагрузке программа, написанная на C#, будет занимать в разы больше оперативной памяти, чем таже самая Java

 даже если это и так, то какое это имеет отношение к сложности освоения Java/C#? Не знаю насчет Питона, никогда с ним не сталкивался, но то, что Java более сложен (причем, судя по вашим словам, гораздо более) чем C# - это явная чепуха. Особенно если вы исходите из своего личного опыта - при всем уважении, опыт одного единственного человека - не более чем статистическая погрешность. Из приведенных вами возможно лишь C++ более сложен, нежели те же C# и Java

Comment: > Но мне с огромным трудом даётся Haskell

Haskell не нужен. Дальнейшие вопросы отпадают сами по себе.

Comment: @SuperCreeper мне очень понравилась Ваша фраза:

     Идеальным началом (да и не началом) являются языки ООП (Объектно-ориентированное программирование).

Так и тянет переформулировать: "Идеальным окончанием ..."

@Flammable а откуда уверенность в том, что

      Haskell не нужен. Дальнейшие вопросы отпадают сами по себе.

Из отсутствия вакансий?

Answer (score -5):

Если хотите серьезно, то лучше начинать с С++. Си перед этим изучать не обязательно. Ну а ресурс могу посоветовать следующий: http://3dmax-lessons.ucoz.ru/publ/programmirovanie/c/6

Там начиная от установки компилятора, руссификация и далее без сплошных терминов и т. д. Все доступно и ясно.

Comment: Что, серьезно? Вы пишете статьи по C++?

Comment: @stranger140569, Вы серьезно решили посоветовать человеку **на каникулах** начать изучение программирования с крестов? 

И испортить ему как эти каникулы, так и будущую жизнь?

Или свою рекламку на сайте (по Вашей ссылке) распространяете?

Comment: Лично я начал с Visual Basic, а затем в нем разочаровался. Пусть парень наступит на те же грабли? Так?. А что насчет рекламы, я понимаю ели бы я разместил эту ссылку на форуме, где учатся вышивать крестиком, но этот сайт кажется посвящен программированию, или я ошибаюсь и здесь учатся чему-то другому? Без обид, ничего личного, и без желания кого-либо обидеть из участников дискуссии.

Comment: @stranger140569, Вы считаете НОРМАЛЬНЫМ отсылать на сайт,  где в правом верхнем углу висит реклама, загораживающая часть текста, которая предлагает отключить себя, выводя поверх всего другую рекламу:

         Установите современный браузер без рекламы!

?????


---

По поводу языка для начального обучения. Не знаю, как там VB, а C++ язык очень сложный (хотя его Си подмножество весьма просто и почти везде логично). 

А при самообучении на каникулах еще следует иметь в виду количество времени, которое придется затратить, для получения первого интересного результата своего труда.

Comment: Я думаю в этом в ваших словах есть определенный смысл.