# Как лучше учить новый язык?

Tags: любой-язык

У меня есть 2 пути, либо читать множество книжек. 
Либо брать проект и на ходу всё пытаться понять.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [С какого языка начать?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233333/%d0%a1-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Путь номер два. И ещё желательно работать в офисе бок о бок с другими прогерами - тогда въедешь быстро. Правда первые года 2 всё равно неизбежно говнокод и нехорошие решения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше совместить оба пути, так как простое чтение не к чему не приведет, так как заблудится со временем.

А чтение с конструированием реального проекта принесет больший профит.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно взять проект и чтобы у Вас был наставник, который обережёт вас от гавнокодерства и покажет как следовать шаблонам программирования. А также после практики будет полезно почитать про другие возможности языка на котором Вы пишите проект и поделать что-то как домашнее задание. К примеру сайт www.acmp.ru содержит в себе множество задач разных уровней для людей с разным уровнем знаний. Особенностью идеи является соперничество среди других программистов, что усилит Вашу мотивацию и старательность.

Удачи.